# 'symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libdevcrypto.so' when running eth or mix?

Tags: cpp-ethereum, mix

I am getting the following error when running eth or mix:

```
symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libdevcrypto.so: undefined symbol:       _ZN8CryptoPP10RandomPool34GenerateIntoBufferedTransformationERNS_22BufferedTransformationERKSsy
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What system are you on? Where did you get download the binaries, and which versions?

Comment: It was working before. I am using Ububtu 15.1. And I installed from  the ethereum repo.

Comment: Removing and re-installing cpp-ethereum fixed it, but that's not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to reinstall eth, mix and all dependencies:

#### Ubuntu 14.4

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --reinstall install -y libboost-random1.55.0 libboost-system1.55.0 libboost-thread1.55.0 libc6 libcurl3 libgcc1 libjson-rpc-cpp-dev libjsoncpp0 libreadline6 libstdc++6 ocl-icd-libopencl1 libethereum miniupnpc libleveldb1 libmicrohttpd10 libglu1-mesa freeglut3 libboost-random1.55.0 libboost-system1.55.0 libboost-thread1.55.0 libc6 libgcc1 libjson-rpc-cpp-dev libjsoncpp0 libstdc++6 ocl-icd-libopencl1 libethereum-gui qml-module-qtquick-controls qml-module-qtquick-dialogs qml-module-qtquick-layouts qml-module-qt-labs-settings qml-module-qtwebengine ethereum eth mix
```

#### Other Ubuntu versions

Find out the [dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/a/275733/94697) and reinstall them:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-cache depends eth | grep '[ |]Depends: [^<]' | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d ' ' | xargs sudo apt-get --reinstall install -y
sudo apt-cache depends mix | grep '[ |]Depends: [^<]' | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d ' ' | xargs sudo apt-get --reinstall install -y
```

If this does not do the trick, maybe report the issue [upstream](https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella/issues).