# How to install eth on debian? (symbol lookup error)

Tags: cpp-ethereum, installation, linux, debian

I installed from the ubuntu ppa and got this error.

```
➜  ~  eth
eth: symbol lookup error: eth: undefined symbol: _ZN3dev3eth14EthashGPUMiner14s_numInstancesE
```

What can I do / check?

I'm on debian testing so maybe something conflicts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ubuntu PPAs are not compatible with Debian. The main issue is the **wrong version for libcrypto++-dev** package.

You have to follow the [generic build process for linux](https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella/wiki/Linux--Generic-Building) and compile it from source.

#### Install dependencies

```
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential git cmake libboost-all-dev libgmp-dev libleveldb-dev libminiupnpc-dev libreadline-dev libncurses5-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libcrypto++-dev libjson-rpc-cpp-dev libmicrohttpd-dev libjsoncpp-dev libargtable2-dev llvm-3.7-dev libedit-dev mesa-common-dev ocl-icd-libopencl1 opencl-headers libgoogle-perftools-dev qtbase5-dev qt5-default qtdeclarative5-dev libqt5webkit5-dev libqt5webengine5-dev ocl-icd-dev libv8-dev libz-dev
```

#### Compile from source

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella
cd webthree-umbrella
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make -j $(nproc)
```

#### Found binaries:

```
./build/libethereum/ethminer/ethminer
./build/libethereum/lllc/lllc
./build/libethereum/ethvm/ethvm
./build/libethereum/ethkey/ethkey
./build/libethereum/test/testeth
./build/alethzero/alethzero/alethzero
./build/alethzero/alethone/alethone
./build/alethzero/alethfive/alethfive
./build/mix/mix
./build/webthree/exp/exp
./build/webthree/eth/eth 
./build/webthree/test/testweb3
./build/webthree/test/ethrpctest/ethrpctest
./build/libweb3core/test/testweb3core
./build/libweb3core/rlp/rlp
./build/solidity/solc/solc
./build/solidity/test/soltest
```

#### Install

```
make install
```

---

For other users getting this issue with Ubuntu: You have to [reinstall eth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/708/87) and all dependencies:

#### Ubuntu 14.4

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --reinstall install -y libboost-random1.55.0 libboost-system1.55.0 libboost-thread1.55.0 libc6 libcurl3 libgcc1 libjson-rpc-cpp-dev libjsoncpp0 libreadline6 libstdc++6 ocl-icd-libopencl1 libethereum miniupnpc libleveldb1 libmicrohttpd10 libglu1-mesa freeglut3 libboost-random1.55.0 libboost-system1.55.0 libboost-thread1.55.0 libc6 libgcc1 libjson-rpc-cpp-dev libjsoncpp0 libstdc++6 ocl-icd-libopencl1 libethereum-gui qml-module-qtquick-controls qml-module-qtquick-dialogs qml-module-qtquick-layouts qml-module-qt-labs-settings qml-module-qtwebengine ethereum eth
```

#### Other Ubuntu versions

Find out the [dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/a/275733/94697) and reinstall them:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-cache depends eth | grep '[ |]Depends: [^<]' | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d ' ' | xargs sudo apt-get --reinstall install -y
sudo apt-cache depends mix | grep '[ |]Depends: [^<]' | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d ' ' | xargs sudo apt-get --reinstall install -y
```

If this does not do the trick, maybe follow the issue [upstream](https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella/issues/92).

Comment: compile went fine, however now i got : ethminer: error while loading shared libraries: libdevcrypto.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory ||| my bad, sudo ldconfig of course....

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella/issues/234 gives info from myself, maybe could help soneone in the future

Comment: I needed the package libcrypto++-dev not libcryptopp-dev

Comment: Also this doesn't work on Debian Jessie.

Comment: Now I can comment; thanks, reputation-donator :-) Have a look [here](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/6362/2937), I could solve it.

Comment: `cmake ..` gives `CMake Error: The source directory "/home/user/git/webthree-umbrella" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.`

Newer build instructions are at: http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/cpp-ethereum/building-from-source/linux.html

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to comment to 5chdn's https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1450/2937 but SE says "You must have 50 reputation to comment", so until someone rewards me with such points, here.

> Install dependencies    ...

in Debian 8: missing `libjson-rpc-cpp-dev` and `libqt5webengine5-dev`  and `llvm-3.5-dev` instead of `llvm-3.7-dev`

I had worked through everything in the "generic build process for linux" for Debian 8.5 - but I stopped the llvm compilation - it just takes too long.

Finally, I succeeded. Here is my manual:

https://gist.github.com/drandreaskrueger/912e704cfc86fd757277a5fd9bd372d4

May it help. I hope whoever finds this, will now need many hours less.

Comment: Please post your manual here instead of any external sites.